# Getting rid of those unsightly temp vars (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, cgfloat

I have a set of CGFloats used to dynamically calculate height and y-coords for arranging views in my viewDidLoad: method, and once those views are arranged the vars are no longer needed. I was just wondering if there was a way (or even a point) to remove temporary variables within a scope once they're no longer needed, similar to releasing allocations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CGFloat` is just a typedef of `float`. Local variables of type `float` live entirely on the stack and disappear when the function returns, so there is no need to do any housekeeping.

Comment: it's only `float` on 32-bit systems; `double` on 64.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to check on that earlier rather than later. :)